# the meaning of model output number in R for linear regression model

Tags: r, statistics

Do I understand correctly that the value (model output) retrieving from evaluate_model() for the linear regression model is RMSE?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including sample data in plain text format, and the code that generated the output. As it stands we have no idea what you did or where the function `evaluate_model` came from.

Answer (score 0):

No, the column output, `model_output`, is not the root mean square error (RMSE). It is the prediction value for your model.

So it appears that the `evaluate_model()` function is from the [`statisticalModeling` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statisticalModeling).

According to [the documentation for this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statisticalModeling/versions/0.3.0/topics/evaluate_model), it "Evaluate a model for specified inputs" and (emphasis added below)

> **Find the model outputs for specified inputs. This is equivalent to the generic predict() function, except it will choose sensible values by default.** This simplifies getting a quick look at model values.

In other words, this function, `evaluate_model()`, takes inputs and shows you the "prediction" of your input data using the model.

For your instance, `evaluate_model()` will take each row of your data and use the column/variable information (age, sex, coverage) for each row, and fits the data to estimate what the dependent variable would be based on this model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is very clear now.